# Invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'ItemType {aka char}' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, type-conversion, typedef

I keep getting an error: invalid conversion from `const char*` to `ItemType {aka char} [-fpermissive]` I initially thought it was because I was using strings so I changed the typedef to strings and got a different error.  I then changed the typedef back and am unable to understand this error does anyone know what I have done wrong?
My errors or all for the insertion method.

This is my header file

```
#ifndef _LINKED_LIST
#define _LINKED_LIST
#include <string>
#include "Node.h"
#include "PrecondViolatedExcep.h"

typedef char ItemType;
class LinkedList
{
private:
   Node* headPtr;
   int itemCount;           // Current count of list items
   Node* getNodeAt(int position) const;
public:
   LinkedList();
   LinkedList(const LinkedList& aList);
   virtual ~LinkedList();
   bool isEmpty() const;
   int getLength() const;
   bool insert(int newPosition, const ItemType& newEntry);
   bool remove(int position);
   void clear();

   ItemType getEntry(int position) const throw(PrecondViolatedExcep);

   void setEntry(int position, const ItemType& newEntry) throw(PrecondViolatedExcep);
};

#endif
```

This is my main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Emery Plummer" << endl;
    LinkedList* groceryList = new LinkedList();

    groceryList->insert(1, "Turkey");
    groceryList->insert(2, "Cheese");
    groceryList->insert(3, "Bread");
    groceryList->insert(4, "lettuce");
    groceryList->insert(5, "Tomatoes");
    groceryList->insert(1, "Soda");
    groceryList->insert(2, "nachos");

    int numberofItems = groceryList->getLength();
    cout << "My grocery list contains " <<  numberofItems << " number of things, theese are the items: "<< endl;
    for(int position = 1; position <= numberofItems; position++)
        cout << groceryList->getEntry(position) << "is first item" << position << endl;
    return0
}
```

This is my cpp

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <cassert>

typedef char ItemType;
LinkedList::LinkedList() : headPtr(nullptr), itemCount(0)
{
}

LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList& aList)
{
    itemCount = aList.itemCount;
    Node* origChainPtr = aList.headPtr;
    if(origChainPtr == nullptr)
        headPtr = nullptr;
    else
    {
        headPtr = new Node();
        headPtr -> setItem(origChainPtr-> getItem());
        Node* newChainPtr = headPtr;
        while(origChainPtr -> getNext()!= nullptr)
    {
        origChainPtr = origChainPtr -> getNext();
        Node nextItem = origChainPtr ->getItem();
        Node* newNodePtr = new Node(nextItem);
        newChainPtr -> setNext(newNodePtr);
        newChainPtr = newChainPtr -> getNext();
    }
    newChainPtr -> setNext(nullptr);
    }
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
   clear();
}  // end destructor


bool LinkedList::isEmpty() const
{
   return itemCount == 0;
}

int LinkedList::getLength() const
{
   return itemCount;
}

bool LinkedList::insert(int newPosition, const ItemType& newEntry)
{
   bool ableToInsert = (newPosition >= 1) && (newPosition <= itemCount + 1);
   if (ableToInsert)
   {
      Node* newNodePtr = new Node(newEntry);
      if (newPosition == 1)
      {
         newNodePtr->setNext(headPtr);
         headPtr = newNodePtr;
      }
      else
      {
         Node* prevPtr = getNodeAt(newPosition - 1);
         newNodePtr->setNext(prevPtr->getNext());
         prevPtr->setNext(newNodePtr);
      }
      itemCount++;
   }

   return ableToInsert;
}

bool LinkedList::remove(int position)
{
   bool ableToRemove = (position >= 1) && (position <= itemCount);
   if (ableToRemove)
   {
      Node* curPtr = nullptr;
      if (position == 1)
      {
         curPtr = headPtr; // Save pointer to node
         headPtr = headPtr->getNext();
      }
      else
      {
         Node* prevPtr = getNodeAt(position - 1);
         curPtr = prevPtr->getNext();
         prevPtr->setNext(curPtr->getNext());
      }
      curPtr->setNext(nullptr);
      delete curPtr;
      curPtr = nullptr;

      itemCount--;
   }

   return ableToRemove;
}

void LinkedList::clear()
{
   while (!isEmpty())
      remove(1);
}

ItemType LinkedList::getEntry(int position) const throw(PrecondViolatedExcep)
{
   bool ableToGet = (position >= 1) && (position <= itemCount);
   if (ableToGet)
   {
      Node* nodePtr = getNodeAt(position);
      return nodePtr->getItem();
   }
   else
   {
      string message = "getEntry() called with an empty list or ";
      message  = message + "invalid position.";
      throw(PrecondViolatedExcep(message));
   }
}

Node* LinkedList::getNodeAt(int position) const
{
   assert( (position >= 1) && (position <= itemCount) );
   Node* curPtr = headPtr;
   for (int skip = 1; skip < position; skip++)
      curPtr = curPtr->getNext();

   return curPtr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Class LinkedList has this method:

```
bool insert(int newPosition, const ItemType& newEntry);
```

And in `main.cpp` you invoke this method this way:

```
groceryList->insert(1, "Turkey");
```

Now, "Turkey" is of type `const char*` while method `insert` demands second argument to be of type `const ItemType&`. You have defined ItemType as `typedef char ItemType`, so effectively `insert` demands `const char&`. As you know `const char*` (a **pointer**) is something different than `const char&` (a **reference**). You have to either change declaration and definition of `insert` or pass "Turkey" as reference, not as a pointer.